# I was supposed to run the code but this was the error it displays?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

code:(i used to run)

```py
books_titles = []
with gzip.open("goodreads_books.json.gz",'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        fields = parse_fields(line)
        try:
            ratings = int(fields["ratings"])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if ratings > 15:
            books_titles.append(fields)
```

Output:

```py
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-26e670060012> in <module>
      2 with gzip.open("goodreads_books.json.gz",'r') as f:
      3     while True:
----> 4         line = f.readline()
      5         if not line:
      6             break

2 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/gzip.py in read(self, size)
    491                 break
    492             if buf == b"":
--> 493                 raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
    494                                "end-of-stream marker was reached")
    495 

EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines ("\n") for an archive. You should not be doing that ..

The error means that there is no more data byte to read to complete the last line since it does not end with a NL character before the end of the file.

Comment: `gzip.open` decompresses the file. I'm guessing it's a JSON-L file, where each line is a complete JSON value. However, it would be simpler to iterate over the file instead of calling `readline` directly: `for line in f: ...`.